# How to add images in windows with questions?

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to make a quiz with questions and unique image for each question. For example

[image]

I don't know why, but there are no images in windows with questions. For example, there is no image "information.jpg" from file "Quiz.java" in the window with question "What is the capital of the Netherlands?". **How can I put images in windows with questions, put unique image for each question? Please help**

When I chose  the folder with images book.jpg, science.jpg, wisdom.jpg : ‪‪‪C:\Users\syuye\eclipse-workspace\test\src\test, there was an error message

[image]

So I saved the file as utf-8. Maybe it influenced somehow?

to c0der: Yes, I added **e.printStackTrace();**:

```
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));

img.add(picLabel); 

add(img); 

} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Errors occur:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:42)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:47)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:52)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:57)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:62)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:67)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:72)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:77)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
    at test.Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:82)
    at test.Quiz.main(Quiz.java:90)
```

*Quiz.java file*

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Quiz extends JFrame{
    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    CardLayout cards=new CardLayout();
    int numQs;
    int wrongs=0;
    int total=0;

    String[][] answers={
        {"Enschede","Amsterdam","Den Haag","Berlin"},
        {"Slang for Hankechief","Dutch for Keyboard","A Male Sheep","Width of a Cut"},
        {"Euler","Erasmus","Fibonnaci","Archemides"},
        {"Shadow of the Collosus","Lighthouse of Alexandria","Colliseum","Parthanon"},
        {"Cars","Nothing","Planes","Plastic Materials"},
        {"True","False"},
        {"True","False"},
        {"4","5","6","7"},
        {"The Lion King","Hamlet","Death of The Salesmen","Phantom of the Opera"},
    };

    String images[] = {
            "1. information.jpg",
            "2.science.jpg",
            "3.wisdom.jpg",             
            };

    RadioQuestion questions[]={

        new RadioQuestion(
            "What is the capital of the Netherlands?",
            answers[0],
            1,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "What is a kerf?",
            answers[1],
            3,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "Who discovered the number e?",
            answers[2],
            0,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "Which of the following is one of the 7 wonders of the ancient world?",
            answers[3],
            1,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "Which of the following is not made in China?",
            answers[4],
            1,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "True or False, Driving drunk is more dangerous than driving tired",
            answers[5],
            1,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "True or False, The Platypus is a mammal",
            answers[6],
            0,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "How many strings are there on a standard guitar?",
            answers[7],
            2,this
        ),
        new RadioQuestion(
            "Which of these plays is made by shakespeare?",
            answers[8],
            1,this
        )
    };

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Quiz();
    }

    public Quiz(){
        super("Quiz Game");
        setResizable(true);
        setSize(500,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p.setLayout(cards);
        numQs=questions.length;
        for(int i=0;i<numQs;i++){
            p.add(questions[i],"q"+i);
        }
        Random r=new Random();
        int i=r.nextInt(numQs);
        cards.show(p,"q"+i);
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void next(){
        if((total-wrongs)==numQs){
            showSummary();
        }else{
            Random r=new Random();
            boolean found=false;
            int i=0;
            while(!found){
                i=r.nextInt(numQs);
                if(!questions[i].used){
                    found=true;
                }
            }
            cards.show(p,"q"+i);
        }
    }

    public void showSummary(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"All Done :), here are your results"+
            "\nNumber of incorrect Answers: \t"+wrongs+
            "\nNumber of Correct Answers: \t"+(total-wrongs)+
            "\nAverage Incorrect Answers per Quesiotn: \t"+((float)wrongs/numQs)+
            "\nPercent Correct: \t\t"+(int)(((float)(total-wrongs)/total)*100)+"%"
        );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

*RadioQuestion.java file*

```
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RadioQuestion extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    int correctAns;
    Quiz quiz;  
    int selected;
    boolean used;
    //questions
    JPanel qPanel=new JPanel();
    //answers
    JPanel aPanel=new JPanel();
    JRadioButton[] responses;
    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
    //bottom
    JPanel botPanel=new JPanel();
    JButton next=new JButton("Next");
    JButton finish=new JButton("Finish");

    /*public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("RadioButton Test");
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        String[] answers={"wrong1","right","wrong2"};
        frame.add(new RadioQuestion("what's right?",answers,1));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }*/

    public RadioQuestion(String q, String[] options, int ans, Quiz quiz){
        this.quiz=quiz;
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        correctAns=ans;
        //question
        qPanel.add(new JLabel(q));
        add(qPanel);
        //answer
        responses=new JRadioButton[options.length];

        try{
            JPanel img = new JPanel();
            BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("‪‪‪C:\Users\syuye\eclipse-workspace\test\src\test")); 
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            img.add(picLabel);
            add(img);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        for(int i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            responses[i]=new JRadioButton(options[i]);
            responses[i].addActionListener(this);
            group.add(responses[i]);
            aPanel.add(responses[i]);
        }
        add(aPanel);
        //bottom
        next.addActionListener(this);
        finish.addActionListener(this);
        botPanel.add(next);
        botPanel.add(finish);
        add(botPanel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src=e.getSource();
        //next button
        if(src.equals(next)){
            showResult();
            if(selected==correctAns){
                used=true;
                quiz.next();
            }
        }
        //finish button
        if(src.equals(finish)){
            quiz.showSummary();
        }
        //radio buttons
        for(int i=0;i<responses.length;i++){
            if(src==responses[i]){
                selected=i;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showResult(){
        String text=responses[selected].getText();
        quiz.total++;
        if(selected==correctAns){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text+" is correct\nWell Done :)");
        }else{
            quiz.wrongs++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text+" is wrong\nSorry :(");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the program throws exceptions. Please post them. (You may not see the exceptions because you do nothing with them: change `catch (Exception e) {}` to  `catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}`  )

Comment: "My guess is that the program throws exceptions. Please post them."

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040261/how-to-add-images-in-windows-with-questions?noredirect=1#comment96862563_55040261) the post and add essential information to it rather than as comments. While you are at it, mark the line that throws the exception so we know which one is it. (RadioQuestion.java:62)

Comment: Yes, I changed catch (Exception e) {} to catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} ) . Errors occur. I wrote about them above in my question.

Comment: You did not mark the line which throws the exception.  I assume it is this one: `ImageIO.read(new File("‪‪‪C:\Users\syuye\eclipse-workspace\test\src\test"));`  which looks like a wrong path and image name.  Run the code in my answer and change it so it shows **your** image.

Comment: The backslash must be escaped in a string, `"\\"`. Or you might use `/`. If the image can be packed in the application as read-only file, as _resource_ (=on the class path), you can use `getClass().getResource("/.../...")`. Check for examples on the net.

Comment: So I can use code like this BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("‪‪‪C:/Users/syuye/eclipse-workspace/test/src/test")); ? But error occurs

Comment: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at test.RadioQuestion.<init>(RadioQuestion.java:61)
 at test.RadioQuestion.main(RadioQuestion.java:44)

Comment: I am not good at programming. Please help

Answer (score 1):

To make help easier always post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , like the following example.
Note that it contains only the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem (or as in this case the solution). It is **not** meant to demonstrate your application.
It uses publicly available resources, so it can be copied and invoked:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RadioQuestion extends JPanel{

    private static final String bug = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Crystal_Project_bug.png";

    public static void main(String args[]){
         JFrame frame=new JFrame("Image Test");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.add(new RadioQuestion());
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public RadioQuestion(){

        try{
            BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new URL(bug));
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
            add(picLabel);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Now take this working code, and try to use it with your images, to easily figure out what's wrong. 
Side note: never mute exceptions by `catch (Exception e) {}`.

Comment: I suspect the OP will face further problems by trying to load images by `File` rather than `URL` (but that's not the immediate problem). Good advice in general, though. It should get them 90% of the way to 'working'. Side tip: DYK there are a variety of images available for hot-linking in in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556)?